# Mail Triggering In Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

I want to setup a Jenkins in a such a way that it should trigger an email when test case fails. I have some 1000+ test cases, if anyone of the test case fails, it should trigger email.

Comment: if test fails then your build should fail and then you should get an email by setting it up in post build step

Comment: I should get mail as soon as test case fails, the other test case will be running. I will be getting mail after executing 1000+ test case as a build status.

Comment: What is your question? You've told us what you want but you haven't told us what problem you're having and what you need help with.

Comment: Hi Bryan. How to configure if anyone of the test case fails out of 1000 test cases it should trigger mail.

Answer (score 0):

Use customized robot listeners as part of the framework, so that they trigger an email everytime for failure

Comment: Thanks Harshavardhan Konakanc! Will try it.

Comment: Please could you explain more? How could it help in triggering mail if test case fails?

Comment: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-listener-interface

Comment: Thanks Harsha! Will go through it!